# Rails (param is missing or the value is empty)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I am using rails 4 and I've read that attr_accessible is beter not to use in this version. I have created that code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end

  private
  ## Strong Parameters 
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

But it gives me out this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#new
param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

I am trying to display that html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.label :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Typically the `new` action would be `@user = User.new` as there are no `user_params` getting posted back from the view.

Comment: in this case, it gives out an error that passwords are undefined methods

Comment: Making progress... let's address your comment about `attr_accessor`.  Not sure where you read that, but I think you'll need to define any attributes not persisted in your model that way.  Can you update your post with your model code?

Comment: Well, added this `attr_accessor :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation` to the model, but now I get the error `Couldn't find User with 'id'=create` (in the show fuction)

Comment: `def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
   if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
   else
    # render :text => "here"
    render action: "new"
   end
  end`

Comment: `def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end`

Comment: Please put your code back to before you added `attr_accessor` and update your original post with your model code.  My guess is that you need `has_secure_password`.

Comment: Add them to your question John, not as comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Solved the problem. I just haven't thought about attr_accessor, Thanks Steve

Comment: Just please be careful John.  If you aren't using `has_secure_password` and `BCrypt` I strongly recommend reading up on them.  For instance, Hartl's [Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) explains this in detail and shows how to roll your own authentication system.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the advice. But what so you think about this encryption: `self.salt = Digest::SHA2.hexigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}") if self.new_record?
   self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the new action would be `@user = User.new` as there are no `user_params` getting posted back from the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end 

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Basically while instantiating an object, you don't need to call user_params .